# Heavy Javascript Lag with Sticky Divs (VanillaJS)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I've been trying to implement a sticky div solution in replacement of fixed elements. This is mainly because of a theoretically better support system for reduced window size on desktop browsers... (i.e. horizontal scrolling compatibility).

I've been implementing the code below, and it works flawlessly in firefox. However, in internet explorer, the entire script lags and the page becomes extremely jumpy.. Since I'm overlaying a bunch of divs, this creates a bit of a mess in terms of presentation. Is there any way to speed up the script to the point where it will run nicely in internet explorer and other untested browsers?

```
window.onload = (function() {
    var oa_sticky = document.getElementsByClassName('sticky_div');

    var oia_sticky_offsets_temp = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < oa_sticky.length; i++) {
        oia_sticky_offsets_temp.push(new Array(oa_sticky[i], (oa_sticky[i].offsetTop)));
    }

    var oia_sticky_offsets = oia_sticky_offsets_temp;

    stick_div(oia_sticky_offsets);

    window.onscroll = function() {
        stick_div(oia_sticky_offsets);

    }

});

function stick_div(oia_sticky_offsets) {
    var doc = document.documentElement;

    for (i = 0; i < oia_sticky_offsets.length; i++) {
        oia_sticky_offsets[i][0].style.top = (doc.scrollTop + oia_sticky_offsets[i][1]) + "px";
    }
}
```

Any help on getting this to respond faster would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: Well, because the divs have to be able to be scrollable (horizontally, not vertically) at reduced window sizes. Fixed divs will not scroll in any direction.

I would implement a fixed div and switch it to absolute or relative at smaller resolution, but some of the navigation has to be accessible at all times, thus it needs to follow the user...

And thus the code above

Comment: You have an error in line 1. `window.onload is not a function. it should be window.onload = (function()`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was uploading it and I have an external function that adds load events... When uploading I just switched it out to window.onload so that I didn't have to bog it down with another function... My bad! Thanks! :)